# Sort random integers descending from highest to lowest instead of lowest to highest?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RandExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {




            int MethodChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What method would you like to use to sort the random numbers" + "\n" + "1 - Selection Sort" + "\n" + "2 - Bubble Sort" + "\n" + "3 - Insertion Sort" + "\n" + "4 - Quick Sort"));

            if (MethodChoice == 1) {

                    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                    int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalCount; i++) {
                            array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(1001);
                            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                    }


                    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
                    selectionSort(array);

                    //print out sorted list
                    System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort," + " the array is:");
                    for (int count = 0; count < array.length; count++) {
                            System.out.print(array[count] + " ");
                    }
            } else if (MethodChoice == 2) {

                    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                    int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalCount; i++) {
                            array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(1001);
                            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                    }


            System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
             bubbleSort(array);

             //print out sorted list
             System.out.println("After sorting using the Bubble Sort,"
                             + " the array is:");
             for (int count = 0; count <array.length; count++) {
                     System.out.print(array[count] + " ");

      }



            } else if (MethodChoice == 3) {


                int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < iTotalCount; i++) {
                        array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(1001);
                        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                }


        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
         bubbleSort(array);

         //print out sorted list
         System.out.println("After sorting using the Insertion Sort,"
                         + " the array is:");
         for (int count = 0; count <array.length; count++) {
                 System.out.print(array[count] + " ");

  }



            } else if (MethodChoice == 4) {

                int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < iTotalCount; i++) {
                        array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(1001);
                        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                }


        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
         bubbleSort(array);

         //print out sorted list
         System.out.println("After sorting using the Quick Sort,"
                         + " the array is:");
         for (int count = 0; count <array.length; count++) {
                 System.out.print(array[count] + " ");

  }










            }



    }


    public static void quickSort(int data[], int low, int high) {
        int partitionLoc;
        if (low < high) {
          partitionLoc = partition(data, low, high);
          quickSort(data, low, partitionLoc - 1);
          quickSort(data, partitionLoc + 1, high);
        }
      }

      public static int partition(int data2[],int left,int right) {
        boolean moveLeft = true;
        int separator = data2[left];

        while (left < right) {
          if (moveLeft == true) {
            while ((data2[right] >= separator) && (left < right)) {
              right--;
            }
            data2[left] = data2[right];
            moveLeft = false;
          } else {
            while ((data2[left] <= separator) && (left < right)) {
              left++;
            }
            data2[right] = data2[left];
            moveLeft = true;
          }
        }
        data2[left] = separator;
        return left;
      }



    public static void bubbleSort(int data[]) {
        //Loop to control number of passes
        for (int pass = 1; pass < data.length; pass++) {
          //Loop to control # of comparisons for length of array-1
          for (int element=0;element<data.length-1;element++) {
            //compare side-by-side elements and swap them if
            //first element is greater than second element
            if (data[element] > data[element + 1]) {
              swap(data, element, element + 1);  //call swap method
            }
          }
        }
      }


    public static void swapBubble(int array2[], int first, int second) {
        int hold = array2[first];
        array2[first] = array2[second];
        array2[second] = hold;

    }


    public static void insertionSort(int data[]) {
        int insert;

        for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
          insert = data[next];
          int moveItem = next;

          while (moveItem > 0 && data[moveItem - 1] > insert) {
            data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
            moveItem--;
          }
          data[moveItem] = insert;
        }
      }



    public static void selectionSort(int data[]) {
            int smallest;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                    smallest = i;
                    //see if there is a smaller number further in the array
                    for (int index = i + 1; index < data.length; index++) {
                            if (data[index] < data[smallest]) {
                                    swap(data, smallest, index);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }





    public static void swap(int array2[], int first, int second) {
            int hold = array2[first];
            array2[first] = array2[second];
            array2[second] = hold;



    }
}
```

I tried looking but they were for lists, I want to prompt the user to see if they'd like to output the sort from ascending or descending. I'm not quite sure how I can do that, I've seen functions using reverse but I do not know how to apply that to my code.

Comment: Do you actually understand how exactly the sorting works in your code?

Comment: It seems highly unusual to me that "you" can implement a quick-sort algorithm but not understand how to change the direction of a sort.

Comment: @wadda_wadda, I've done the algorithms in VB last year in school, but never learned how to change the order, just how to write them. At my school we were spoonfed how to do everything with code examples where we were to C&P them, and to just change the variables, which I know is probably bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print your array backwards.

```
for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
 System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

Comment: I think I may have declared my array somewhere in a code block where it can't be accessed when in others(tells me to initialize the variable), I tried adding the same array in the code block(which looks super ugly with all of the array declaration) and when I tried, it printed the array the same way except this time with 4 zero's before the randomly generated numbers.